# How to make a change that affect several site at once?

Tags: database, multi-sites

We have two Drupal 7 and two Drupal 8 website for an airline company. We want the staff at the airport to upload a flight schedule in such a way that it will get displayed in all the four sites at once. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You'll need to use the [RESTful Web Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/restws) module for D7. In D8 this module already comes with D8 Core.

Comment: I actually get it to work with RSS feed. This should be a better approached, will definitely try it out. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by uploading the schedule to one site and then exposing an RSS feed for the other sites to pull it down.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but this works great for me, thanks.